# How do you add a textbox on top of a streambuilder within Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I must have something wrong with my structure.

I have a listview built dynamically using Firestore and it works great, however I am trying to add a textbox on top of the list in order to create a "filter" or "search".

Here is the example code:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
//  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Testing App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Testing App'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Widget _buildListItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document){
    return Card(
        //height: 50,
        color: Colors.amber[600],
      //padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("Image"),
            width: 85,
              //height: 75
          ),
          Expanded(
              //color: Colors.cyan,
              //padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
              child: Row(
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      //Icon(Icons., color: Colors.green[500]),
                      Text("Text 1", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text(document['test1'].toString()),
                      Text("Text 2", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text(document['test2'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ]
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing App"),
      ),
      body:
        <<------ ADD TEXT BOX HERE ---->>
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('firestoretest').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 80.0,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.docs[index])
              );
            }
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried adding the streambuilder within children and nothing shows up.

This is a modified version of the example I found within the google tutorials.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if that solves it.

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Testing App"),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Text("<<------ ADD TEXT BOX HERE ---->>"),
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('firestoretest')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemExtent: 80.0,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]));
              }),
        )
      ],
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your streamBuilder, wrap your ListviewBuilder with a Column, and on top of it, put your text widget. Use the ShrinkWrap property of listView builder and set it to 'true', this is why you weren't seeing any results, because there was a render flex error.
Like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('firestoretest').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
          return Column(children[
          Text('Hiii'),
          ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true, 
          //This is very important, without shrinkWrap, you'll get an error 
          //saying:'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
          //Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
          //The relevant error-causing widget was Column.

            itemExtent: 80.0,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.docs[index])
              ]));
            }
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: As you mentioned that you wanted to add a text box for searching, you'll need the newly updated items from the stream, that's why it should be inside the stream builder I assume.